# Cannot paste multiple lines of code in Python using Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I am trying to paste Python code through anacdona's powershell which was activated through Windows' CMD. However I am having trouble pasting multiple lines of code. It seems to read it as all one line and returns an error.

Really hoping there is an answer that doesn't require editing my code with carrots or semicolons?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import pickle
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows CMD is notably a troubled terminal emulator. However, it was updated significantly in Windows 10 - I just tested copy-pasting the above example on Windows 10 and it works absolutely fine... they separate out into individual lines entered into the python terminal.

Other alternatives that don't involve updating windows:

- Actually using the real powershell.exe, though I don't know if this will work either
- copy-pasting into a file, and loading the code from the file
- using cygwin/git bash for windows and using the unix pipe operator (|) to pipe input to python

Comment: Hm, I do not have such luck unfortunately (using Windows 10 too)

Comment: what version of python is installed? Can you literally try the following:

1)Win + R
2)Type "cmd"
3)Hit Enter
4) Type "python"
5) Hit Enter, >>> should show up
6) Copy the following (I can't put newlines into the comment unfortunately, you will have to edit the following in notepad or something):

    x = 1
    y = x + 1
    print( x + y )

5) Paste into CMD window

You should see "3" show up